# UIAlertController changes isModalInPopover behaviour

Tags: ios, swift

I found out the UIViewController will change the isModalInPopover behaviour of the presented Popover view controller on iPad.

I have 2 view controllers: first one `ViewController` has a button to present another view controller `MyViewController`, by using **Present as Popover** segue. In my code, I set the destination view controller's `isModalInPopover` to true to prevent the popover get dismissed by tapping outside of the popover view:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

        if segue.destination.popoverPresentationController != nil {
            segue.destination.isModalInPopover = true
        }

    }

}
```

On my second view controller, just a simple button to present an alert view controller:

```
class MyAlertViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Just an alert.", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: { _ in
            (sender as? UIButton)?.setTitle("\(self.isModalInPopover)", for: .normal)
            // self.isModalInPopover = true // comment out to restore the behaviour
        }))

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Once the alert controller has been dismissed, the MyAlertViewController's isModalInPopover behaviour has been changed too - **now I can tap on outside of the popover view to dismiss it**, even the value of isModalInPopover is still `true`. I have to manually set the value to `true` again to prevent this change.

I want to know why this happen and is there any better way to prevent the alert controller to change this behaviour?

[image: Screenshot of the storyboard]